# What`s the differences between Sequences and Sequence Items?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

What are the main differences ? 
When should I choose to work with sequences and when with sequence items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [sequence](https://verificationguide.com/uvm/uvm-sequence/) generates a series of sequence_item’s and sends it to the driver via sequencer. Thus, `body()` method of a sequence defines sequence_item’s that will be used.

On the other hand, a sequence item is the basic transaction used by the driver to drive the interface.

The following picture from [UVM Basics tutorial](https://www.aldec.com/en/company/blog/158--understanding-the-inner-workings-of-uvm-part-2) explains it fully:

[image]